# Looking to get results where they are the same on two columns and different on another SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sort of a beginner to SQL Server.. and I want to get results for when there is more than one SYS_ETL_SOURCE for a given LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR for a DISTRICT_CODE.

```
SELECT DISTRICT_CODE, LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR, SYS_ETL_SOURCE
FROM K12INTEL_DW.FTBL_ENROLLMENTS
GROUP BY DISTRICT_CODE, LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR, SYS_ETL_SOURCE
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

The above query gets me all data for each school year and each sys_etl_source, but I would like to only see those which have more than one SYS_ETL_SOURCE for a given year.

Edit:

This is what I am looking for...

| district_code | local_school_year | sys_etl_source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2020-2021 | ETL_SOURCE 1 |
| 1234 | 2020-2021 | ETL_SOURCE 2 |

This is what I currently get

| district_code | local_school_year | sys_etl_source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2018-2019 | ETL_SOURCE 1 |
| 1234 | 2019-2020 | ETL_SOURCE 1 |
| 1234 | 2020-2021 | ETL_SOURCE 1 |
| 1234 | 2020-2021 | ETL_SOURCE 2 |
| 1234 | 2021-2022 | ETL_SOURCE 2 |

Edit 2:

This is what FTBL_ENROLLMENTS looks like...

| enrollments_key | student_key | start_date | end_date | district_code | local_school_year | sys_etl_source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | xxxxxxxxx | 1/01/2020 | 6/31/21 | 2021 | 2020-2021 | ETL_SOURCE |

We have some school years that have different sys_etl_sources and because of that there are some duplicate records.

Comment: can you share some sample data and the expected output from relative to the provided input?

Comment: Providing the current output and the expected output is a great way to improve your post, though could you share the content of your input table `K12INTEL_DW.FTBL_ENROLLMENTS` too? This would allow people to reproduce your environment and provide an accurate solution for your issue @sswift8

Answer (score 1):

You can get this using a correlated subquery (I added an alias for your initial table to be E1 for simplicity/clarity):

```
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT DISTRICT_CODE, LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR, COUNT(*) 
  FROM K12INTEL_DW.FTBL_ENROLLMENTS E2 
  WHERE E1.DISTRICT_CODE = E2.DISTRICT_CODE 
        and E1.LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR = E2.LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR 
  GROUP BY DISTRICT_CODE, LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: `EXISTS (SELECT Column1, Column2...` is the same as `EXISTS (SELECT 1` or `EXISTS (SELECT NULL`. Also the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary as those columns are already correlated

Comment: The optimizer filters them out, but I put them here since the OP said they were new to SQL for clarity.

Comment: IMO it makes it less clear what is actually happening, but as you say, they get filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

A window function is probably the most efficient

```sql
SELECT
  e.DISTRICT_CODE,
  e.LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR,
  e.SYS_ETL_SOURCE
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.DISTRICT_CODE, e.LOCAL_SCHOOL_YEAR) AS count
    FROM K12INTEL_DW.FTBL_ENROLLMENTS e
) e
WHERE e.count > 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe8ceb53fde6b64c24af321982da61f9)

Comment: It actually is not - it spools while the solution I posted does not (usually) spool.

Comment: Depends if you have Batch over Rowstore, and depending on indexing probably still more efficient than a correlated subquery. YMMV